# Cannot translate pseudo-code to java

Tags: java, arrays, string, logic

I got some test code, in a form of pseudocode, from my friend. He asked my help to post here.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
function g(string str) returns string
  int i =0
  string new_str = ""
  while i < len(str) - 1
    new_str = new_str + str [i + 1]
    i++
   end
   return new_str
end

function f(string str) return string
  if len(str) == 0
    return ""
  else if len(str) == 1
    return str
  else 
    return f(g(str) + str [0]
  end
  end

function h(int n, string str) returns string
whlie n != 1
  if n % 2 == 0
    n = n/2
  else
    n = 3 * n + 1
  end
  str = f(str)
  end
    return str
end

function pow(int x, int y) returns int
  if y == 0
    return 1
  else 
    return x * pow(x, y-1)
  end
end

print (h(1, "fruits"))
print (h(2, "fruits"))
print (h(5, "fruits"))
print (h(pow(2, 1000000000000000), "fruits"))
print (h(pow(9831050005000007), "fruits"))
```

I've tried to convert it to Java syntax, but I got an error in line 20 and 32, which says :

> Incompatible types : String Cannot be converted to String []

Here the code that I made :

```
public class TestLogic{
    public  String g(String[] str){
        int i=0;
        String new_str = "";
        while(i < (str.length -1)){
            new_str += str[1 + i];
            i = i + 1;   
        }
        return new_str;
    }

    public String f(String[] str){
        if (str.length == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        else if (str.length == 1){
            return str.toString();
        }
        else {
            return f(g(str)) + str [0];
        }
    }

    public static String h (int n, String str){
        while(n!=1){
            if (n%2==0){
                n= n/2;
            }
            else{
                n =3*n +1 ;
            }
            str = f(str);
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static int pow(int x, long y){
        if (y==0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return x * pow(x, y-1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(h(1, "fruits"));
        System.out.print(h(2, "fruits"));
        System.out.print(h(5, "fruits"));
        System.out.print(h(pow(2, 1000000000000000l),"fruits"));
       System.out.print(h(pow(2, 9831050005000007l),"fruits"));

    }
}
```

To be clear here, I am not programmer. And I am really new in Java and programming world.

Comment: Yes..............................

Comment: `g(str)` is returning a String which you cannot pass to function `f`

Comment: Either OP needs to wrap the said String into an array of String, or change the function definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend doesn't use a String-Array in his example (which is in another programming language), he uses a normal String.

When he accesses the string with the brackets `string [i + 1]`, the translatet code in java would be `string.charAt(i+1)`. So just change your String-Arrays to a normal String.

Comment: This is helping.  Thank you. I change all the String[] to string. And the length to length() method too. But I got trouble with third and fourth output. My friend said that i should use biginteger in my output. I already tried that, but got an error said Biginteger cannot be converted to int. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

In f and g you are passing sa a parameter aj array of Strings (String[])
String cannot be converted to aj array of Strings so if you delete [] brackets in the type of parameter of those two functions it should work.